# Is it a good idea to save/load an array of struct?

Tags: c++, fstream

I was wondering if it was a good idea to load/save an array of a certain type of structure using fstream. Note, I am talking about loading/saving to a binary file. Should I be loading/saving independent variables such as int, float, boolean rather then a struct? The reason I ask that is because I've heard that a structure might have some type of padding which might offset the save/load.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking us to compare.  Could you provide some simple code snippets of each alternative?

Comment: "deprecated" has a special meaning in C++ circles - I've rephrased your question to avoid its use.

Comment: I don't have chapter & verse handy, but I'm sure it's invalid to load/save an array of non-POD objects.

Comment: @Rob Nope, the C++ standard is silent in that regard.

Comment: @Rob: This is where the language allows "the programmer to shoot their foot."  An array of `struct` or `POD` is an area in memory where the items are located contiguously.  The binary I/O outputs from an area in memory, no restrictions (accessing of invalid memory locations is caught by platform or OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A structure may contain padding, which will be written to the file. This is no big deal if the file is going to be read back on the same platform, using code emitted by the same compiler that did the write. However, this is difficult  to guarantee, and if you cannot guarantee it, you should normally write the data in some textual format, such as XML, json or whatever.

Comment: +1, Extending:  Different platforms and OS revisions may represent data differently in binary.  One such case is Endianness.  Also, data structure fields should be written singularly with some kind of separator between fields.

Comment: By represent data differently, you mean Endian wise, not the amount of size it occupies in binary right?

Comment: @Johnathan No, I don't mean that. A structure in C or C++ can take up different amounts of space even on the same platform. But endianess is a definite issue for portability. Note this may not matter - if you are writing an ap on say Windows which needs to read & write very fast, then writing structs direct is probably the way to go, but your datafiles will not be portable.

Comment: So doing it this way means that it might not work on Linux or Mac.

Comment: @Johnathan No, it WILL work everywhere. However, the file produced will be completely unportable.

Answer (score 1):

Without serialization, your binary data will not be portable across different platform (and compilers). So if you need portability, then you need to serialize the data before storing it in file as binary.

Have a look at these:

- [Boost Serialization Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)
- [Boost Serializable Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not deprecated (it's not part of any formal spec, where should it be deprecated?), but it's extremely not portable and probably the worst way to go about serialising stuff. Use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/), or a similar library.

Comment: using a serialization library is overkill if binary compatibility is not a problem (program will run only on the same platform/OS and structure is guaranteed to be the same in future versions)

Comment: @CharlesB: And the same compiler and the same version of that compiler will always be used. It's just not portable at all, and not using a serialisation library can only cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in your answer this will happen with writing structs this way. If you want your files to be portable across platforms, e.g. file being written on Linux i686 to opened by Solaris on Sparc then even writing individual float's won't work.

Try writing your data to something like text or XML and then zip/tar the files to make one document of them.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil said, prefer textual representation of data.  The XML format may be overkill.  Simpler versions are Comma Separated Value (CSV) and one value per text line.